# Rvest encountering error 503 when trying to webscrape

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am attempting to scrape a website for information, however when I attempt to grab the information using RVest, I get an Error 503 message. See below for my code to see what I am doing:

```
url <- c("https://www.gunviolencearchive.org/incident/2310278")
df <- read_html(url)
```

This results in the following error:

```
Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : HTTP error 503.
```

I have already searched this topic, and the two most common answers were to define a User Agent and use a Sys.Sleep() step in each scraping step. However, I have tried using a user agent to no avail, and since this is happening on my first scraping attempt, I do not think a system pause will help.

If it helps, when you navigate to the page in question you get a message that reads "checking your browser before navigating", which I believe is the root of the issue I'm encountering.

Does anyone have experience with this specific kind of issue? Thanks!

Comment: It looks like they're using bot-fighting software: https://developers.cloudflare.com/bots/reference/javascript-detections/

Comment: How did you get to the website "https://www.gunviolencearchive.org/incident/2310278" from the website "https://www.gunviolencearchive.org/"? I am able to get to "https://www.gunviolencearchive.org/" with RSelenium. If you tell me how you got to the website, we might be able to replicate it with RSelenium.